# How to write a new scripted data set which uses results from other data sets in BIRT?

Tags: javascript, birt

I have 2 sets of compacted data relating to hotel bookings for an industrial fair. One is a list of hotel block reservations and the second is a list of actual occupancy.

I need to expand this to display reservations and occupancy for each hotel and each day.

As the data is compacted (no reservation for a day, no DB record), I thought I could create a scripted data set which expands the data and fills in the empty days. Information from the 2 data sets can be then brought together in the script.

How could I do this? Can I pass a data set result as a parameter? Can I execute a SQL data set from the scripted data set?

Here is an example:

DS1 (Block reservation)

```
HotelA, RoomTypeX, From1, To1
HotelA, RoomTypeX, From1, To1
HotelA, RoomTypeX, From2, To2
HotelA, RoomTypeY, From3, To3
```

DS2 (Occupancy)

```
Hotel   Room       Date  Rooms booked
-------------------------------------
HotelA, RoomTypeX, Day1, 0
HotelA, RoomTypeX, Day2, 1
HotelA, RoomTypeX, Day3, 3
HotelA, RoomTypeX, Day4, 2
```

Report

```
Hotel   Room       Day1   Day2   Day3 ....
------------------------------------------
HotelA  RoomTypeX  0/2    1/3    3/3
HotelA  RoomTypeY  0/0    1/1    1/1
```

Report shows occupancy and reservation for each day of the fair for each hotel.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use a joint data set with a scripted dataset that pads out dates, like what is posted here:
http://www.birt-exchange.org/org/devshare/designing-birt-reports/1543-joint-data-set-to-pad-out-dates/